# QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate (QuickBooks POS 19.0 + QuickBooks Web Connector 2.1.0.30)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbwc

I am trying to sync my OpenCart inventory with a QuickBooks POS module via the QuickBooks Web Connector. The documentation says to only use Web Connector version 2.1.0.30 for QB POS. I install the Web Connector on the computer running QB POS 19.0. When I try to add an application I get an immediate QBWC1048 error. Here is the full log output with certain redactions:

```
20211010.14:08:00 UTC : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
<AppName>OpenCart + QBPOS</AppName>
<AppID>id</AppID>
<CertURL>https://fitsfashions.com</CertURL>
<AppURL>https://fitsfashions.com/index.php?route=account/qbposwc</AppURL>
<AppDescription>OpenCart + QBPOS</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>https://fitsfashions.com/index.php?route=information/contact</AppSupport>
<UserName>username</UserName>
<OwnerID>{a60d1e19-bfbb-5b94-e1a8-a34570dc1ed9}</OwnerID>
<FileID>{081bcf7f-6f6a-70c4-0935-cd28bfc05603}</FileID>
<QBType>QBPOS</QBType>
<Notify>false</Notify>
<Scheduler>
<RunEveryNMinutes>5</RunEveryNMinutes>
</Scheduler>
<IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20211010.14:08:00 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20211010.14:08:00 UTC : : QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate.


Certificate URL: https://fitsfashions.comStackTrace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at QBWebConnector.QWCReader.CheckCertURL()

Message (description of the exception):
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Source (name of application or object that caused the exception):
System

TargetSite (method that threw the exception):
System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()

InnerException:

 

20211010.14:08:01 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate.

QBWC1051: The new application was not added
```

As you can see, I've tried adding the CertURL option with no luck. I also get the same error while running the troubleshooter .qwc file from https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootQBWC/index.aspx. I've looked all over the internet and put in help tickets but somehow no one seems to have a working solution other than the CertURL thing. The website uses a valid cPanel v3 certificate. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

According to Intuit's documentation ( https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-quickbooks-web-connector ) `Web Connector version 2.1.0.30` supports these TLS versions:

- `support up to TLS 1.0`

But your web server doesn't support that old version of TLS:

```
SSL v2  not offered
SSL v3  not offered
TLS 1.0 not offered
TLS 1.1 is not offered
TLS 1.2 offered
TLS 1.3 offered with final
```

This is good, because TLS 1.0 is insecure, and should not be used.

You probably want to upgrade to a newer version of the Web Connector, which supports newer versions of TLS:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-quickbooks-web-connector#download-and-install-the-quickbooks-web-connector